# how to use one value of a listbox to set another listbox's value?

Tags: javascript, html, listbox

I am learning Javascript for the first time.
I am trying to select one value for listbox1 and based on that value it must select the value in listbox2.

This is what i coded.

```
<html>
<head>
    function choose() {
        if(document.getElementById('City').value===1) {
            document.getElementById('subcity').value ="1";
            document.getElementById('subcity').text ="Adyar, chennai";       
        }
    }
</head>

<body>
    <select name="City" onchange ="choose()" onclick="" id="City" >
        <option value="0">Select City</option>
        <option value="1">Chennai</option>
        <option value="2">Bangalore</option>
    </select>

    <select name="subcity" id="subcity" >
        <option selected="selected" value="0">Select sub area</option>
        <option value="1">Adyar, chennai</option>
        <option value="2">Electronic city, bangalore</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

But it didnt seem to change or set the second listbox. It still showed me all the options i had inside it.

Can you please tell the correct way of setting values in the listbox2?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery

```
 $('#City').change(function() {
    $('#subcity').val($('#City').val());
 });
```

Put this on a separate js file and call it from the html: http://jsfiddle.net/Re8Cc/

Comment: Hello asiviero, Im not aware of jQuery but i'll read and find about how to work with that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: jQuery will make your life way easier once you learn it, it's a powerful lib that makes javascript coding easier and more dynamic